# Matlab: Cannot find the callback invoked by right-click delete for impoly/imfree

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I'm creating ROIs using `imfree` / `impoly`. I need my program to know when they are moved or deleted. For moving, I'm using `addNewPositionCallback` which works perfectly.

When deleting a ROI using the built-in right-click "delete", the ROI disappears from the axes but my software is unaware that anything has happened. There seems to be no documentation for how to create a similar callback for delete. How can I achieve this?

Minimal code:

```
figure;
imagesc(fspecial('ga‌​uss',20,2));
colormap gray;
P = [ 10.3387 6.0685; 6.6982 9.1589; 9.1406 14.3484; 13.5184 13.3571; 14.1175 7.7012];
hROI = impoly(gca,P);
addNewPositionCallba‌​ck(hROI,@(pos)fprintf‌​('Successful move!\n'));
```

Notice that moving the ROI (mouse left click and dragging) generates a callback. I want to be able to invoke a callback when I delete the ROI using the existing right click -> "delete".

Comment: please provide a minimal example  of code. (read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details).

Comment: Edit the question instead of commenting.